# Dont open drop down in AutoCompleteTextView

Tags: android, autocomplete

I use this code for **AutoCompleteTextView** - so when you delete the last character to show the list. But **mAutoCompleteTextView.showDropDown();** dont work.

```
mAutoCompleteTextView.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
        @Override
        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {

        }
        @Override
        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {


        }
        @Override
        public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
            if (s.toString().equals("")) {
                mAutoCompleteTextView.showDropDown();
            }
        }
    });
```

Comment: WHy you have put your code in aftertextchanged? not in ontextchanged?

Comment: Dont work in onTextChanged too

Comment: Probably because s.toString never matches "" or maybe AfterTextChanged doesn't get fired when the textfield is empty. Usually it requires at least 1 character to start.

Comment: You want to show the list when all the characters are deleted?

Comment: Yes - I want to show the list if all characters are deleted

Answer (score 2):

> When initializing the widget, I remembered the adapter in a class field.
>   use this to set adapter

```
mAdapter = (ArrayAdapter<String>)actv.getAdapter(); // mAdapter is a class field        
actv.setText("Tim Hortons"); 
actv.setSelection(0, actv.getText().length()); 
actv.setAdapter((ArrayAdapter<String>)null); // turn off the adapter
actv.requestFocus();
Handler handler = new Handler() {
 public void handleMessage(Message msg) {
((AutoCompleteTextView)msg.obj).setAdapter(mAdapter);
};
Message msg = mHandler.obtainMessage();
msg.obj = actv;
handler.sendMessageDelayed(msg, 200);
```

> hope this will help you

Comment: ok add this proprties to textview mContactTxt.setFocusable(false);
mContactTxt.setFocusableInTouchMode(false);
mContactTxt.setText("");            
mContactTxt.setFocusable(true);
mContactTxt.setFocusableInTouchMode(true);